# The firefox open the link in current tab, the link I edit it open in new window by kindeditor

Tags: javascript, firefox

when I edit the link in my blog by kindeditor, I choose the link open in new window. Actually, the link will open in new tab in chrome and IE， but it will open in current tab in firefox.
I have found the ralated code in kindedior plugin,as follows:

```js
urlBox.val('http://');
typeBox[0].options[0] = new Option(lang.newWindow, '_blank');
typeBox[0].options[1] = new Option(lang.selfWindow, '');
self.cmd.selection();
```

How to modify the code to realize opening the link in new tab in firefox/IE/chrome?

Comment: Browsers have options how to show opened windows, you can't really choose it.

Comment: Thanks. But The "new Option(lang.newWindow, '_blank');" could open new tab in IE and Chrome, that must be some code could open new tab in firefox.

Comment: Again: you can't affect on how browsers open a new window, it is controlled by settings. IE for example has three options, either open in a new tab, open in a new window, or let browser decide. When the latter is selected, you can open a tab or a window. If either of two former options is selected, there's nothing you can do within a HTML page to choose the way.